# Oracle:Tricky Update and Insert Inside loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I an trying to write a query or pl/sql for the following criteria.

I have a 1st query which returns list of accountId's and accountNumbers.

```
select mbr.accountId, ac.accountNumber 
  from Member mbr, Account ac
 where mbr.status ='A'
   and mbr.accountId=ac.accountId
 group by mbr.accountId,ac.accountNumber
having count(*)>1;
```

**Second Query:**

```
with ca as
(select customerNumber from customer
where status = 'A' and accountId in (
select accountId from customer where accountId = 123
group by accountId having count(accountId) > 1
))
select * from customer where customerNumber not in
(select customerNumber from customer group by customerNumber having count(customerNumber) > 1)
and customerNumber in (select customerNumber from ca);
```

Based on the accountId from 1stquery, get list of customer where account have more than one customer,Mostly it will have two customers, one customer with just this account and another customer have multiple accounts associated.Then we have to update customer status to 'I' which have only one account.

And also have to insert accountId,accountNumber (got this two from first query) and customerNumber(get this from second query).

How I make **update and also insert** into another table which requires 2 parameters from 1st query and one from second query??

```
Create Table Account(accountId number(10),accountNumber number(10));
Create Table Member(accountId number(10),MemberNumber number(10),status char(1));
Create Table Customer(accountId number(10),customerNumber number(10),status char(1));
Create Table audit_cust(accountId number(10),accountNumber number(10),customerNumber number(10),status char(1))


Begin
 Insert into account(accountId,accountNumber)values('123',001);
 Insert into account(accountId,accountNumber)values('234',002);
 Insert into account(accountId,accountNumber)values('456',002);
 
 Insert into Member(accountId,MemberNumber,status)values('123',980,'A');
 Insert into Member(accountId,MemberNumber,status)values('123',981,'A');
 Insert into Member(accountId,MemberNumber,status)values('456',983,'A');
 Insert into Member(accountId,MemberNumber,status)values('456',984,'A');

 Insert into Customer(accountId,customerNumber,status)values('123',427,'A');
 Insert into Customer(accountId,customerNumber,status)values('123',428,'A');
 Insert into Customer(accountId,customerNumber,status)values('367',428,'A');
 Insert into Customer(accountId,customerNumber,status)values('456',428,'A');
 
 commit;
End;
/
```

**1st Query Result:**

[image]

**Second Query Result:**

[image]

After Update

[image]

**After Insert**

[image]

Comment: `merge` probably the right candidate here. Could you provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Updated the question with necessary script.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer inserting into `audit_cust` table first, and then update `customer` table depending on the matched values of `account[number/id]` and `customernumber` columns for these tables :

```
INSERT INTO audit_cust
SELECT ma.accountNumber, ma.accountid, customernumber, 'I' AS status
  FROM
  (
    SELECT mbr.accountId, ac.accountNumber
      FROM Member mbr
      JOIN Account ac
        ON ac.accountId = mbr.accountId
     WHERE mbr.status = 'A'    
     GROUP BY mbr.accountId, ac.accountNumber
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) ma
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT c.*, 
           COUNT(c.accountid) OVER (PARTITION BY c.customernumber) AS count
      FROM customer c
     WHERE status = 'A') cc
    ON cc.accountid = ma.accountid 
 WHERE cc.count = 1
```

Notice that I used analytical function `COUNT() OVER ()` for the second subquery and filtered out the records counted `1`, based on your second query.

And, then we can update the `customer` table :

```
UPDATE customer c
   SET c.status = ( SELECT a.status
                      FROM audit_cust a
                     WHERE a.accountnumber = c.accountid
                       AND a.customernumber = c.customernumber )
 WHERE EXISTS
       ( SELECT *
           FROM audit_cust a
          WHERE a.accountnumber = c.accountid
            AND a.customernumber = c.customernumber
            AND a.status = 'I' )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e75b403260013e4f2f87d190ee57f529)</kbd>

Comment: I realise that I misread your comment. Using cursor also might be preferred @Arnold , but using these two statements recursively as in the answer is more straightforward.